# How can I transform my dataframe containing columns for each timepoint to a dataframe with one row per timepoint and patient?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is structured  like this:

| Patient | day1_temperature | day1_blood | day2_temperature | day2_blood |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patient1 | 37.5 °C | 120 | 38 °C | 126 |  |  |  |
| Patient2 | 38 °C | 129 | 38 °C | 132 |

There is one row for each patient and the values from different timepoints are all in one row.

But I want to have a dataframe which has several rows for one patient and each timepoints is one row.
It should have this structure:

| Patient | day | temperature | blood_pressure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patient1 | 1 | 37.5 °C | 120 |
| Patient1 | 2 | 38 ° | 126 |
| Patient2 | 1 | 38°C | 129 |
| Patient2 | 2 | 38 °C | 132 |

I tried to use melt() on my dataframe, but it didn't lead to the right result.
Is there a pandas function which I can use to transform my dataframe in the described way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with some preprocessing for integer values to end of columns names in list comparehension:

```
df.columns = [f'{"".join(x[::-1])}' for x in 
              df.columns.str.replace('day','').str.split('_')]
print (df)
    Patient temperature1  blood1 temperature2  blood2
0  Patient1      37.5 °C     120        38 °C     126
1  Patient2        38 °C     129        38 °C     132

df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                      stubnames=['temperature','blood'],
                      i=['index','Patient'],
                      j='day')
        .reset_index(level=[1,2])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
    Patient  day temperature  blood
0  Patient1    1     37.5 °C    120
1  Patient1    2       38 °C    126
2  Patient2    1       38 °C    129
3  Patient2    2       38 °C    132
```

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract the solution a bit by using the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor

(
    df.pivot_longer(index="Patient", 
                    names_to=("day", ".value"), 
                    names_pattern=r"day(.)_(.+)")
      .rename(columns={"blood": "blood_pressure"})
)


    Patient     day     temperature     blood_pressure
0   Patient1    1       37.5 °C         120
1   Patient2    1       38 °C           129
2   Patient1    2       38 °C           126
3   Patient2    2       38 °C           132
```

The `names_pattern` argument uses a regular expression, with groups, to reshape the data. In this case we have two groups, one that matches the number after `day`, the other matches the text after `_`, which is temperature or blood. `names_to` determines how the data is returned. if there is a '.value', then that value remains as a column name. in this case, `.value` is paired with `blood|temperature`, so those stay as columns, while the numbers are collated under `day` column.